# simple example for sharing data between resources is not working

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

index.html is as:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTTP Request</title>

  <script src="angularjs"></script>
  <script src="appjs"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <p>Data sharing example :</p>
        <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="numval">
            <p>Inside first DIV : {{numval}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="numval">
            <p>Inside second DIV : {{numval}}</p>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And app.js is as :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('sharedata', function() {
    return 'common data';
});

    myApp.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'sharedata', function($scope, $http, sharedata) {
        alert('first');
        $scope.numval='first';
        $scope.numval=sharedata;
    }]);

    myApp.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'sharedata', function($scope, $http, sharedata) {
        alert('second');
        $scope.numval='second';
        $scope.numval = sharedata;
    }]);
```

I am unable to find the stupid mistake....! I am expecting that whether I change data in first input box or in second, I should see the changes reflected in both the DIV tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('sharedata', function() {
    return {numval: "Something"};
});

myApp.controller('firstCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'sharedata',
    function($scope, $http, sharedata) {
        alert('first');
        $scope.sharedata = sharedata;
    }]
);

myApp.controller('secondCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'sharedata',
    function($scope, $http, sharedata) {
        alert('second');
        $scope.sharedata = sharedata;
    }]
);
```

And the HTML, both `<div>`s:

```
        <input type="text" ng-model="sharedata.numval">
        <p>Inside ___ DIV : {{sharedata.numval}}</p>
```

---

Your mistakes:

- `$scope.numval='first'; $scope.numval=sharedata;` doesn't make sense...
- The `sharedata` service is returning a value; you cannot change a value; you should return a reference (i.e. the object) that *contains* the value. That way both scopes can *write* to it.